# "Adjustment performed successfully" or "Adjustment performed with successfully"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, phrase-usage

I don't understand the lack of **'with'** in the phrase below.

> Adjustment performed ***successfully***.

Google Translate does not use **WITH**, and I don't understand why.

Comment: Adverbs don't need *with*. Tell me, OP, where is it that you've seen *with successfully* used, or any other *with* *adverb ending in ly* used? If you're seeing that, that's part of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably confused ***with success*** with ***successfully***."With" is a preposition and needs a noun. "Successfully" is an adverb and does not need to be preceded by a preposition.

[Powerthesaurus](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/with_success/synonyms) says they are synonyms:

> ***with success*** = ***successfully***

Consider

> She has completed her mission ***with success***.

and

> She has ***successfully*** completed her mission.

Both are possible, but [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=with%20success%2C%20successfully&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwith%20success%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuccessfully%3B%2Cc0) will tell you that ***successfully*** is much more common.

Of course, you may have come across contexts like

> There is no evidence that more complex cases cannot be ***dealt with*** successfully.

The expression is *to ***deal with something*** successfully*. In this expression, the preposition *with* is not connected with *successfully* but with *something.*

Edit: Re-written in the active voice, the sentence would be

> There is no evidence that one cannot ***deal with*** more complex ***cases*** successfully).

Here, it is even more obvious that the preposition ***with*** is connected to ***cases*** (definitely not with *successfully*.

Comment: Good answer. I'd quibble with your last paragraph. The object of "with" is "cases", not an elided "something". The sentence could be reworded (omitting the passive) as, "There is no evidence that one cannot deal with more complex cases successfully".

Comment: @Jay You are right for the sentence, but I was analysing _**the expression**_ I had indicated in the previous sentence. And I left it in the passive to give an example of **with successfully** next to each other.

Comment: Oh, I agree, for your post to make your point you absolutely had to start with "dealt with successfully". And I get saying "dealt with something" to explain the phrase. I just think you stopped a step short of a complete explanation. Anyway, not trying to argue about it, just trying to clarify what "something" is in this case.

Comment: @Jay It is very good you pointed that out. I will edit gladly, anything that can improve an answer is welcome, and especially when it is indicated politely :-)